# Locate path of assets files in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using a package (Starflut) that needs to use a file which I store in assets.

I first add this file to the pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
    - my_folder/my_file.py
```

I have then been trying to find this file while running the app, but it is in none of the following directories or any of its subfolders:

- /data/user/0/com.example.my_app
- /data/data/com.example.my_app

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';

...

var aux=Directory("/data/user/0/com.example.my_app");
//var aux=Directory("/data/data/com.example.my_app/files");
var files = aux.listSync(recursive:true).toList();
print(files[2]);
for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
  print(files[i]);
}
```

And the following code returns the paths below:

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory(); // /data/user/0/com.example.my_app/cache
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // /data/user/0/com.example.my_app/app_flutter
```

How can I locate the assets/my_file.py so that I can use it from the package (starflut)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your asset is packed with application you will have to copy the file from rootBundle to temp directory or your desired location. You can check out this [medium post](https://medium.com/@wangdazhitech/flutter-read-asset-file-and-write-to-app-path-42115d4ec1b6) on how to read asset file and write to app path.

Hope this helps.